# If $n$ divides $m$, then $n$ divides $m^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have been asked in one of my problem sheets to prove that if $3$ divides $n$, then $3$ divides $n^2$.

So what I did was: Write $n=3d$, $d$ is an integer. So $n^2=9d^2$, therefore $n^2=3*3d^2=3c$, where $c$ is an integer.

QED.

But then the same method works in general for any number other than $3$.

Where am I making a mistake?

Comment: Nowhere, there is no mistake, why do you want one ?

Comment: The question is ... Why do you think you are making a mistake ?

Comment: Notice that $m|m^2$, and the divisibility property is transitive... However, usually what is proved that resembles question is: if $3|n^2$, then $3|n$ (then actually $9|n^2$).

Answer (score 1):

You have no mistake,

$n^2 = n*n$

therefore, if m divides n:

$n=mc,c\in Z$

$n^2=m(mc^2)$

$mc^2\in Z$

therefore m divides $n^2$.

Answer (score 0):

$$n|m\implies m=qn\implies m^2=q^2n^2=rn\implies n|m^2.$$

The converse isnt' true. For instance, $9|36$ but $9\not|\ 6$.

Answer (score 0):

See that $n^2=n.n$.
 Now we are given that $3|n$ or $3k=n$ for some integer $k$.
 Substituting it in the first result, we get $n^2=3k.n$. 
 Let $kn=p$ for some integer $p$, so $n^2=3p$ which shows that $3|n^2$. 
 
**Remark:** Can you prove the converse of your question also? That is, if $3|n^2$, then prove that $3|n$. (But keep in mind that the number which is dividing will always be a prime). Otherwise, it won't be true.  
Hint: Use the fundamental theorem of Arithmetic.

Comment: It doesn't have to be prime, it just can't have any square factors.  If $210|n^2$ then $210|n$ because each prime factor of $210$ is only a factor once.

Comment: Ohk, yes. But lets confine it to $2,3,5,7\cdots$  primes.

Answer (score 0):

If k divide n it means that exists an integer c such that 
n = k*c

and, conversely, if exists an integer c such that n = k*c 
then k divide n

So n^2 = k^2 * c^2 = k * (k c^2) so k divide n^2. 
No problem

If also k is PRIME, then it's true even the opposite : 
k | n^2 => k | n

Thats because for any PRIME p : p | ab => (p | a or p | b)

Now look here :

suppose p | a^n ; then p | a

Proof :

Suppose p not divide a

then p | a^n => p | a or p | a^(n-1)
But we supposed p not divide a, then must be 
p | a^(n-1) so again p | a^(n-2) or p | a

and so on, until you get that p | a

So if you suppose not p | a you get a contradiction
(not p | a AND p | a)

Then, p | a 
CvD